# how to make on subview in objective-c something like overflow:hidden in CSS?

Tags: objective-c, view, visibility, xib

I've got view in XIB which has on start 43 pixel height. This view has UIImage below 43 pixel height (position 0, 44). When i tap on the view, it grow and its height is 187 and image is loaded and visible. When i tap on view second time, view is 43 pixel height but this image on this view is stil visible (content after y = 43 is visible). Is it possible to hide this content which is above 43 pixel height? (out of view).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i solved it!

The answer is:

```
    [self setClipsToBounds:YES];
```